# response.sendRedirect not working in spring MVC RequestMethod.DELETE

Tags: java, spring-mvc

From Angular JS page, when I click on submit, request hits my RestService and after processing the request, I'm trying to do a response.sendRedirect to an external application url. It doesn't redirect. I tried adding a return statement just after the redirect call. But it doesn't redirect. Still the same old page appears on the Browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getExit", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)

  public void getExit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      ...................
       response.sendRedirect("url");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that you did not write to output stream anything before redirect call

Comment: No, nothing is being written to output stream.

Comment: what is the response code you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in this way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getExit", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String getExit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  ...................
   return "redirect:url";
}
```

Comment: What is the difference? Is this the way we should redirect?